# ircd-hybrid operator doesn't work

Tags: 12.10, ircd-hybrid

I've installed **ircd-hybrid** in my network, now I'm operator and I receive operator privs, something like this:

```
*** Oper privs are <SOME CODE HERE>
```

But I cannot manage anything in my server, I want to assign channel operator to a user, I can't. I want to de-assign channel operator privs, I can't, and so on.

I was not able to find a guide on google related to commands of **irc**.

When I type `/operserv` something I receive `/operserv` is not recognized by server.
When I `/msg operserv` it says unknown nick or channel

Please help.
Thanks in advance.